# Access ID of object in collection of objects (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a Collection of objects in VBA and each object has a unique ID. I understand I can access the 'items' in a collection which is an inbuilt function of VBA. Is there a way I can access the object's id? (i'm not sure how to set up the loop..

Currently I am doing something like:

```
For each objectName in CollectionName

objectName.Item(index)

Next objectName
```

This is correct syntax for accessing the collection's Item, but I am unable to delve into the collection to get the object's/item's ID...is this possible?

fyi, the object's id is set up as mID and is an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `Collection` class does not offer an iterator for the IDs. :-(

If you want this, use a `Dictionary` object instead! It is part of the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime' (to be selected in Tools->References) - and works like a Collection - but with a lot of additional functionality.

Here's an example:

```
Public Sub TestDictionary()
    Dim dict As New Dictionary
    Dim var As Variant

    dict.Add "Key1", 1
    dict.Add 2, "Item 2"
    dict.Add "Another key", "blabla"

    For Each var In dict.Keys
        Debug.Print var, dict(var)
    Next var
End Sub
```